# The Least Interesting Substance

Tags: science-based, chemistry

There are many interesting places, many interesting worlds. This world is not one of them. It has an argon atmosphere, and the planet itself is made of a very unreactive, insoluble, extremely difficult to erode, not at all shiny or luminous, monotone grey powder. It is about as dense as sand.

You need not think of how this world came to be, but if you can think of a very good reason why such a planet would come to be, then by all means say it. If necessary, the substance may be synthetic, but avoid anything along the lines of complex or organic molecules.

To eat it would be pointless, but it should not poison you if you did. The alchemists who teleport there babble about the dust having unlimited potential, but then nobody actually takes them seriously. Perhaps it does have such properties.

What is the best candidate for such a material?

Comment: "doesn't erode" - is it the only distinct characteristic that differentiate this sand from regular sand?

Comment: @Alexander Apart from being grey and montone, it is also more opaque, and is less reactive and soluble than silicon dioxide.

Comment: Silicon dioxide is not really soluble, and quite inert chemically. Admixtures will make it gray and opaque (there are plenty of gray sands here on Earth). That leaves, from my point of view, only hardness. Quartz is 7 on Mohr scale - you need more?

Comment: Is this set in ancient times? Future? You mention alchemists and teleportation, which generally speaking don't go together. Maybe a few more details like that, and a summary of what you are actually looking for

Comment: Philosophically speaking, can you really have a [least interesting planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox)...

Comment: Unreactive, insoluble, abrasion-resistant material?  Sounds like a great substance to make your alchemy equipment out of.

Comment: @Giter Yes. The smallest uninteresting thing is no more interesting than a relatively medium sized one. Every uninteresting thing is unique, but they are still boring.

Comment: Unobtanium, because a planet can't be (naturally) formed from single minerals, much less boring, grey powdered ones.

Comment: the stone is in fact a solidified argon :D unlimited... lights?

Comment: If your planet is covered in sand, what do you mean by saying that the  sand doesn't erode? Sand gets blown about by the wind.

Comment: Helium 3? [Yeah, that's ours.](https://youtu.be/uimh2EBB1yQ?t=59)

Comment: @DavidRicherby What I mean is, it would be at no risking of breaking down into smaller particulates here on earth for any forseeable period of time.

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for but [this](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/) would definitely keep any self-respecting intelligent life away ;)

Comment: Do the alchemists babble while breathing Argon?

Comment: @KalleMP Yes, but also when not.

Comment: So you want something as boring as dirt?

Comment: An argon atmosphere is actually quite interesting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon#Applications

Comment: Nothing explodes in argon, ergo it is uninteresting to alchemists.  Now if the atmosphere were a 14.7 to 1 ratio of naptha to oxygen ....

Comment: How about the crushed bone-dust of accountants and tax auditors?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Welcome to **Planet Basalt**!

---

**You want grey? You got grey.** Basalt [is mainly composed of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt#Geochemistry) silicon dioxide(white colored), magnesium oxide(white), calcium oxide(white), aluminum oxide(white), and iron(II) oxide(black). [The darker grey areas that you see on the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_mare) are basalt dust. If there was wind on the Moon, it would definitely be boringly covering the entire surface rather than being in concentrated mildly-interesting 'seas'.

**You want simple? You got simple.** [Basalt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt) is formed when silicate-heavy lava cools rapidly when exposed to the surface. Because of the rapid cooling, large crystals don't often form in it, giving a very monotonous, fine-grained texture.

**You want dust? You got dust.** Basalt [weathers quickly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt#Weathering) compared to many other rocks, so the winds on this planet will quickly turn the surface into dust. It's good that the planet has a non-oxygen atmosphere, as a lack of free oxygen will prevent the iron commonly found within basalt from [oxidizing and turning red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Basalt_structures.jpg).

**You want alchemists to think it's useful? Alchemists could think it's useful.** Basalt dust can be used to make a [mineral wool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_wool) called [basalt fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt_fiber). This fiber can be used as thermal insulation, and thermal insulation isn't that interesting to the common person. However, the fact that a *vocanic rock can be alchemized into fire resistant cloth* is enough to get any alchemist interested.

---

**Addition**, because I forgot it needed to be more boring than sand:

**You want more boring than sand? 90% of basalt is more or equally as boring than sand. The other 10% might catch on fire.** Most [sand on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sand) is composed of silicon dioxide, [which is quite reactive and somewhat water soluble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide#Chemical_reactions). Let's see how [the major components of basalt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt#Geochemistry) compare to silicon dioxide:

- Silicon dioxide, 45-55%. About half of basalt is just regular sand, so about half is at least as boring/interesting as sand.
- Magnesium oxide, 5-12%. Magnesium oxide [is prized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_oxide#Applications) for being physically and chemically stable at high temperatures, it lowers acidity, and is not very water soluble. So, a bit more boring than sand.
- Calcium oxide, <10%. Unfortunately, [calcium oxide reacts with water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_oxide#Usage) and produces heat, so it definitely is more interesting than sand. However, it neutralizes acids and dehydrates whatever it touches, so in a way it makes *other* things boring. Furthermore, if just enough water was evenly added to the planet then all of the water and calcium oxide would combine and become [calcium hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_hydroxide). This chemical is used in the food industry due to "the mildness of its basic properties", which is an exceptionally boring description.
- Aluminum oxide, >=14%. Aluminum oxide is primarily just [used to make aluminum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide#Applications). Other than that, the fact that is pretty inert means that is used as a catalyst in the production of other chemicals, i.e. it makes other things interesting without becoming interesting itself.
- Iron oxide, 5-14%: Iron oxide is [used as a pigment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(II)_oxide#Uses) because of its consistent coloration and water insolubility, so it's quite nonreactive. However, this means that it can be used to make interesting tattoos.

**In summary, the components of basalt are mostly boring, with one notable exception.** About 50% is just regular sand, about 35-40%(magnesium oxide, aluminum oxide, iron oxide) are used in applications where being inert is a good thing, and 10%(calcium oxide) heats up when exposed to water. **That last 10% of calcium oxide could be what the alchemists are interested in, whereas normal people just see the boring 90%.**

Comment: Basalt weathers down mostly to a common silica sand. However, if atmosphere is argon, that won't be the case. That sand, however, will be more chemically reactive than silica.

Comment: @Alexander: I don't think argon would bind with anything in the basalt, so how would physical weathering from argon wind produce anything more chemically active than what was already in the basalt?

Comment: @Giter it needs to not just be unreactive on the planet, but also more boring than sand on earth, except for alchemical purposes

Comment: @Piomicron: Ah, I understand now. I'll check how reactive the non-silica bits of basalt are and add that to the answer.

Comment: @Piomicron: Updated the answer. Turns out 90% of basalt is decently boring, and 10% catches on fire when wet.

Comment: Well, Magnesium *Oxide* is quite stable and makes good pots for holding molten metal when mixed with Silica and Aluminium Oxide, but Magnesium *Metal* has a bad habit of bursting into flames and will happily keep burning even when being smothered with a CO2 fire extinguisher.

Comment: @Giter can the non-boring 10% be removed without risk of the other 10% becoming interesting?

Comment: @Piomicron: You could add just enough water to the planet to turn the water and calcium oxide into [calcium hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_hydroxide). This won't affect the other 90% of the basalt components since they are not very water soluble, and calcium hydroxide is used in the food industry because of the "mildness of its basic properties", which certainly sounds boring.

Comment: I just have to say that you explained one of the most boring materials in a very entertaining way.

Comment: "*physical weathering from argon wind*" Does wind -- by itself, not carrying sand, moisture, etc -- do any weathering?

Comment: @RonJohn: Yep, the argon atoms will cause at least *some* abrasion as it blows over the basalt, though I'm not sure how much. However, I think most of the action will come from the wind moving small rocks/pebbles over the surface.

Comment: @skout: Explaining boring things well is a surprisingly useful skill in life.

Comment: @Ronjohn, the lunar surface is eroded by the solar wind, which is mostly protons. I think Argon would be more effective.

Answer (score 20):

It's deactivated [Grey goo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_goo), [Smartdust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartdust), [Programmable matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_matter), [Computronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computronium), or something like that.

Basically trillions of nano machines that at some point in the past ate the planet and converted it all into more machines, and then when there was nothing left they turned off. Now it's just this inert dust like stuff. After all this time it's probably harmless...

**Edit: So something a little simpler.**
If you are looking for something like a single element/compound, you could look into most of the transition elements. They are all metal, and non-reactive.

Best possibility I can think of might be powered [Aluminium oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide). It's hard, dull grey, and would be extremely interesting to alchemists.

Something like a tungsten dust. It has a dark grey color.

Another possible option is impure carbon. It's very hard, and with the right impurities would be opaque, though possibly not dull.

Comment: I really like this answer, and I've upvoted it, but unfortunately, it's not really what I'm after.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/865/

Comment: @Cody Internet of *Hungry* Things

Comment: It is actually an old poo pellet from Great A'Tuin (https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Great_A'Tuin) that has fully decomposed

Answer (score 12):

[image: graphite powder]

- Unreactive - check.  Crucibles can be made of graphite.  [Graphite is the most stable form of carbon under standard conditions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite)
- Insoluble - check.  Except it is soluble in chlorofluoric acid or molten nickel.

  - Difficult to erode.  Not sure about this.  It is already a powder as requested.  It does not really have anywhere to go, erosionwise.
  - Monotone - check.  Take a look.
  - Dense as sand.  SiO2 = 2.65 g/cm<sup>3</sup>   Graphite = 2.26 g / cm<sup>3</sup> .  Close enough?
  - Poisonous.  Nope.  Eat up.
  - How it came to be:  Lightning in a methane atmosphere produces graphite and soot.  This stuff snows down.  It piles up.  It piles deep.
    https://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/news/1203/lightning-mixes-a-dark-and-stormy-brew-at-saturn/
  - Unlimited potential: yes.  Graphite as graphite is indeed good for a lot of different things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite.  But graphite is an avatar of the goddess Carbon, and carbon is the stuff of life.

Answer (score 5):

> You need not think of how this world came to be, but if you can think of a very good reason why such a planet would come to be, then by all means say it. If necessary, the substance may be synthetic, but avoid anything along the lines of complex or organic molecules.

The planet is a worthless ball of rock whose only remarkable quality is a resistance to corrosion and being drilled through. It might be basalt, or granite, possibly mixed with even harder substances (e.g. moissanite - but not large crystals as they might be valuable). It might be covered in soot. The atmosphere is worthless and unbreathable. That's exactly the point.

It has been *engineered* that way to act as an enormous shield for the civilization (possibly virtualized in computronium) that dwells several hundred kilometers beneath. They weren't interested in interstellar voyages, feared that someone warlike or otherwise unagreeable might come by, so they retreated and made their whole system as unappealing as possible.

(I would not be surprised if some smaller asteroids and satellites in the system were actually extreme-endurance self-repairing kinetic energy weapons, designed to stop the occasional wandering planetoid).

> The alchemists who teleport there babble about the dust having unlimited potential

That's more difficult - boring *and* with unlimited potential? Either solve it literally: the dust is *carbon*. Soot, or graphite. Unlimited potential, except it isn't worth the expense to mine from the gravity well. Or it might be made up of the dead nanomachines that deathformed the planet to make it worthless real estate, but in that case the dust might contain some valuable trace elements, which won't do.

Comment: The unlimited potential was edited in. Besides, alchemists might think such things, that doesn't make them true...

Comment: Of course we then ask, "where does a planet-sized ball of basalt come from?

Comment: @RonJohn from lots of solar energy and every other silica-bearing body in the solar system, during a period of several hundred thousand years. These guys took the *very* long view.

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting an interesting question.
Like Giter answered, you could have the surface made of weathered basalt.
Here is my idea for forming the planet:
In a developing solar system, a rocky planet closer than the snow line gets hit by another protoplanet of almost equal size. They hit at an angle so that a large amount of the planet gets pulverized and thrown into orbit as a large ring system, and the main planet gets almost completely melted. The material in orbit however stays as a very separated ring, and no large moons form.

Because the collision was so large, it knocks the planet out of the system and burns away all volatiles that existed on the planet before. Now a rogue planet, far from any star and left to drift for billions of years, it cools down, re-solidifying the rock in orbit and on the surface into basalt. The particles and moonlets in the ring slowly de-orbit, and pulverize the surface into gravel and dust. The rogue planet, left alone for so long, also gradually releases helium gas from decaying uranium in it's core, which is a noble gas unreactive like argon, into the atmosphere, which doesn't get blown away like it does around a star.

The planet is a cold dark body, flying alone under the stars, with a grey dusty and gravelly featureless surface, and an inert transparent helium atmosphere.

Comment: Not bad. Welcome to the site, take our [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Your search is doomed.  The best you can hope for is to make it a moderately uninteresting planet.

Making it ***too*** uninteresting would attract attention.  It would be at the extreme of a bunch of distributions.

So you need to figure out what makes planets interesting to civilizations.

- You want it to have little water.  Most of the processes that concentrate ores into useful concentrations have water in some stage of either the creation, precipitation or transport.  You don't want zero water.  THAT would attract attention.
- You want to have an unremarkable atmosphere but one that is not breathable.  For commercial exploitation a breathable atmosphere makes everything a bunch easier.
- Give it a somewhat larger mass and a somewhat larger diameter.  This makes the escape velocity higher, the atmosphere thicker, and doing anything on the surface more tiring.  The surface light would be dim, the sky murky looking
- Give it somewhat more axial tilt.  This makes the seasons more extreme and more unpleasant.
- For similar reasons give it a longer year.
- Put some unpleasant material in the atmosphere.  Carbon dust, silica dust.  This tends to get everywhere, and make life difficult.  If one of the materials is a moderately bad conductor then it has potential to mess up electronics.
- Your planet formed in a region where there weren't many supernovae, so while the crust has a fair amount of light elements it's impoverished in heavy elements.
- It has little magnetic field due to lack of iron.  Solar wind blasts at the atmosphere.  Good thing you started with greater mass.  The solar wind has finally blasted enough away that you aren't stuck in eternal searing black calm like Venus.
- It's a long way from anywhere, off the beaten track
- The stellar system has no asteroid belt to speak of.

As an example of what some civilizations find interesting, consider Poul Anderson's "Satan's World"  This was a rogue world between stars.  It was going to encounter a fly past near a blue giant star when discovered.

So what use is a frozen planet soon to be well baked?

- It had water.
- No life.
- Normal geology.
- Colder than a banker's heart, mostly.  (A few months near a bright star will revive the atmosphere, get the top of the oceans warm, but do little else.

In his novel they used it for mass transmutation, using the oceans at heat sinks.  As the planet retreated back into the stellar night the level of transmution increased to keep the planet at a reasonable temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on their technological level (I assume they teleported with magic or similar alchemic stuff and not an elaborate highly technological machine), you might also take stuff into consideration that today would be very interesting and valuable like titan but useless in past times because there was no way to easy way of fabrication.