# Would Vesta Be A Suitable Spot For Colonization

Tags: space, asteroids

So I was thinking of using the asteroid Vesta as one of the many asteroid colonies in my future solar system. Is it a viable candidate or is there any "problems" with it. The colony would be made of tunnels bored into the asteroid, I am not concerned over issues like valuable metals, location, or health problems. Just whether or not any trouble would come up trying to bore into it and create tunnels and such.

Edit: Assume a near future technology, handwave life support and such. What I am asking is if you tried to turn Vesta into a bored out warren of tunnels, would they come apart? Would they be structurally unsound? Etc. . .

Comment: Difficulties to bore tunnels depends only on the technology level of your world, something we don't know because you haven't told us.

Comment: so, your question is "Can i bore Vesta ?" and not "Is an asteroid suitable for colonization ?" no problem with absence of atmosphere, extremely low gravity or temperatures?

Comment: Yes, please elaborate on your problem. What do you need from such an asteroid?

Comment: The problem is that there are no reasons to undertake such a project. If you just do it because you can, you have an irrational society which creates many problems. Never not care about motivations to do something.

Comment: If Bruce Willis is there to help, you can bore into any asteroid :)

Comment: How can we answer this?  We don't know the internal composition of Vesta.  We don't know whether or not near-future technology could bore holes gently or will rattle the rock apart.  I'm not trying to be argumentative, but this isn't a necessary question.  Declare it to be so, and move forward with your story.  There is always some fiction in Science Fiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to data from the Dawn mission and what are believed to be meteorites from Vesta, it seems like your bore-d colony shouldn't have much more trouble with their bore-ing task.

Vesta will likely have a solid, uniform crust made of some of the most common rocks found on Earth, so even current drills should be able to bore through it once you solve the low-gravity issues.

---

**Vesta Composition:** [These meteorites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HED_meteorite) are believed to be debris ejected from Vesta as a result of an ancient collision. Presuming they are from Vesta, we have a good idea of what the crust of Vesta is made of. The surface seems to be mostly [basalt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt) and other igneous rocks, which means it is [quite boring](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/106062/46957) but also quite uniform and solid.

**Vesta Geology:** Because of the above rocks(and [other observations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)#Vesta_orbit)), it is [thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_Vesta#Geology) that Vesta formed much like the terrestrial planets, and has a solid and cool core/mantle, and a crust that is 10km thick. This means that the surface of Vesta should be stable, solid, and have plenty of room to bore into.